# Android sqlite insert Null Error

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to automatically insert values into a sqlite database during onCreate in the MainActivity.

Here is some code:

```
public static final String KEY_RULEID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_RULE = "rule";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
public static final String KEY_ENABLED = "enabled";     
private static final String rulesc = "??????";
private static final int typesc = 0;
private static final String enabledsc = "TRUE";

private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /* insert default rules into the database */
private void insertDefaultRule(String rule, int type, String enabled) {
    ContentValues defaultValues = new ContentValues();
    defaultValues.put(KEY_RULE, rulesc);
    defaultValues.put(KEY_TYPE, typesc);
    defaultValues.put(KEY_ENABLED, enabledsc);
    System.out.println("line 175");
    db.insert(Constants.DATABASES_TABLE_RULES, null, defaultValues);
}
```

Line 175 gets printed to the system log so I know that the db.insert line is the source of the error. The main error is a NullPointerException but this is the other half, may be helpful.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(7178):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
E/AndroidRuntime(7178):     at com.prototype.sample.RulesDatabaseAdapter.open(RulesDatabaseAdapter.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(7178):     at com.prototype.sample.RulesDatabaseAdapter.insertDefualtRules(RulesDatabaseAdapter.java:155)
E/AndroidRuntime(7178):     at com.prototype.sample.MessagesList.DefaultRules(MessagesList.java:88)
E/AndroidRuntime(7178):     at com.prototype.sample.MessagesList.onCreate(MessagesList.java:53)
E/AndroidRuntime(7178):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(7178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime(7178):     ... 11 more
```

**EDIT**: added information. This class does extend SQLiteOpenHelper.

Constants.DATABASES_TABLE_RULES is defined in the Constants class as follows:

```
    public final static String DATABASES_TABLE_RULES = "rules";
```

Code to open the DB:

```
    /* opens the database */
public RulesDatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Comment: It seems as if "Constants.DATABASES_TABLE_RULES" is null

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db Instead of using `SQLiteDatabase` you should extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: You need to post your class showing where you open the DB... it seems to be having trouble opening it.

Comment: Please see my edits. I hope it sheds some more light. I'm trying to post relevant code without overwhelming  anyone as my class is fairly large.